# SESSION variable on td button not change

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I have a table where filled by php from database. For each row, there is a button to enter to detail of an user. As I need a reference to user, i order to open his detail table, I use a _SESSION variable to do that:

```
 <td><?php echo $user_id;  ?></td>
 <td ><?php echo $user_name;  ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $user_email;  ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $user_level;  ?></td>
 <td>

 <?php $_SESSION['detailtable'] =  $user_name; ?>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btnVerDatos" aria-label="Left Align" >

  </button>

   </td>
```

If I log the variable $_SESSION['detailtable'], is different for each row.

But when I use it in another php file, as for example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$_SESSION['detailtable']." ORDER BY DataOra DESC";
```

the variable is the the same.

Where is y fault?

Tx in advance

Comment: `$_SESSION['detailtable']` should contain username of last user in table. Is that true?

Comment: do you start session top of you code ?

Comment: michail_w you right. but why is not the row one?